# Why is my NodeJS socket not working without ending the connection?

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

I am really new at programming so I need help with sockets. I have created a Java socket server and now I want to be able to send data from Node.js to the server side. the Node.js client also connects to the server side and then when I use this code:

```js
var net = require('net');
var client = net.connect(12343, 'localhost');
client.write('data1');
client.end();`
```

I get on the server "data1", which is correct. but the client is always terminated, So I would have to make a new connection every time. If I delete `client.end()`
suddenly nothing is sent anymore.

I tried other to do it in one function and other weird stuff, but i dont understand the problem

My Java code (don't be surprised its with spigot):

```
private static ServerSocket serverSocket;

    public SocketHandler() {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(12243);
            Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskAsynchronously(Main.getInstance(), this::startListening);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void startListening() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("connection...");
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskAsynchronously(Main.getInstance(), () -> {
                    try {
                        handleConnection(clientSocket);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void handleConnection(Socket clientSocket) throws IOException {
        InputStream input;

        try {

            input = clientSocket.getInputStream();

            String inputString = inputStreamAsString(input);

            System.out.println(inputString);

            clientSocket.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void stop() {
        try {
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static String inputStreamAsString(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        br.close();
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: The problem might be with the server code. The server could wait in some receive call for a specific amount of data OR until the connection is closed before returning the data to your program.

Comment: Mh, I dont understand the problem yet. I added the code to my post^^

Comment: Your server reads data using `readLine()` which only returns when it receives a line-feed (`"\n"`). You need to send a line-feed with `write('data1\n')`.